# How to make spinner show full items in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

I have a problem with Android Spinner. I customised an adapter with a BaseAdapter. But when it show in the first time, it not show all items (I have only 6 items). Below is the screenshot
http://pik.vn/2014999186b9-448d-44ed-bd9b-c37484b368c6.png

And when I tap to the Spinner second time it show normally. Below is the screenshot. How can I show full item like that at the first time?
http://pik.vn/201454ed3e5b-4c67-4e9c-b8c6-feaf90c5dfb4.png

Update code:

Below is the adapter:

public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

```
Context mContext;
List<CategoryModel> data;
int selectedCate;
boolean isSpinner;
Spinner spn;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryModel> data, boolean isSpinner, Spinner spn) {
    mContext = context;
    selectedCate = 0;
    this.data = data;
    this.isSpinner=isSpinner;
    this.spn = spn;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (position < data.size()) {
        return data.get(position);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_category_spinner, parent, false);

        }
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inflater_category_spinner_tv);
        tvName.setSelected(spn.isSelected());
        tvName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_category, parent, false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cate_image);
    if (!data.get(position).getName().equals(parent.getContext().getString(R.string.browse))) {
        Log.d("postion", "" + position);
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(img, data.get(position).getImage().getUrl());
    } else {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_everything);
    }

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inflater_cate_tv_name);
    tvName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;

}

public void swapView(int position) {
    selectedCate = position;
}
```

}

and below is the code init Spinner in Activity

```
             categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(HomeActivity.this, result,true, mSpnActionbarCenterTitle);
            mSpnActionbarCenterTitle.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```

Comment: I update my code, pls help me review. If you need more information, pls let me know

Comment: @Eu.Dr. do you have any idea?

Comment: convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_category, parent, false); 1> What is the height of this inflater_category? Try giving it a static height and use a scrollView.
2> Or if you fave used matchParent to height attribute, change the last parameter of inflate() to true.

Comment: Thanks @Eu.Dr.I found the problem. The problem comes from the height of ImageView, it is wrap content and load via lazy loader, and the height of spinner not change when image loaded. My solution is fix the size of ImageView. Again, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the height of ImageView, it is wrap content and load via lazy loader, and the height of spinner not change when image loaded. My solution is fix the size of ImageView.